# Not able to catch exception from promise, error response is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got some basic Javascript code that calls a stock API with symbols where the symbols are provided from a simple HTTP call like this:

GET http://localhost:4000/batch_stock_prices/?stocks=12312.

I believe I am misunderstanding the syntax for how to catch an exception from a promise..

An exception gets thrown that 12312 is an invalid symbol which I expect, on the terminal running the node server I see the exception but I'm not able to pass it back in the HTTP response. The error that's passed back in the response is 'undefined'. How can I catch the exception? Do I need a try catch somewhere?

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const { IEXCloudClient } = require("node-iex-cloud");
const { type } = require('tap');


const iex = new IEXCloudClient(fetch, {
  sandbox: true,
  publishable: "pk_2f78524e5........23c327e24b5",
  version: "stable"
});

'use strict'

async function getCurrentPriceOfBatchStocks(_stock) {

  stocks_to_submit = _stock['stocks'];
  console.log(stocks_to_submit)

  response = await iex
    .batchSymbols(stocks_to_submit)
    .price()
    .catch(function (error) { // <-- doesn't seem to get called
      console.log("Exception: " + error);
      throw error;
    })

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (response) {
      resolve(response)
    } else {
      reject(response); // <-- response is undefined. why?
    }
  });
}

const batchStocksSchema = {
  querystring: {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
      stocks: {
        type: 'string'
      }
    },
    required: ['stocks']
  }
}

module.exports = async function (fastify, opts) {

  fastify.get('/batch_stock_prices/', {
    schema: batchStocksSchema
  }, async function (request, reply) {
    try {
      var response = await getCurrentPriceOfBatchStocks(request.query)
      // console.log(response)
      return reply
        .code(200)
        .send(response);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
      return reply
        .code(400)
        .send('Bad Request, exception: ' + e) // outputs: ...exception: undefined
    }
  })

}
```

Comment: If you use `await`, use a `try` … `catch` block (**not** a `catch` **function**)

Comment: Similarly, you almost never need `new Promise`, and particularly not in an `async` function, which has already created one for you.

Comment: You're saying the error occurs in `price()`? It's very hard to tell from the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm not sure if it occurs in price, it could be in batchSymbols. I thought the catch at the end should catch any exception occurring in the chain.

Comment: @qqilihq Where would the try catch go?

Comment: @IanSmith - It will, if the error is in that chain. If it's not being caught there, it's not occurring in that chain.

Comment: Any exception thrown from `getCurrentPriceOfBatchStocks` should be caught just fine in the `try`/`catch` in your fastify handler.

Comment: I've posted an answer to deal with the things qqilihq and I have pointed out above, perhaps the underlying problem was hidden by one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For why the catch is not called in this part:

```
response = await iex
.batchSymbols(stocks_to_submit)
.price()
.catch(function (error) { // <-- doesn't seem to get called
  console.log("Exception: " + error);
  throw error;
})
```

and why response is undefined:

```
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (response) {
      resolve(response)
    } else {
      reject(response); // <-- response is undefined. why?
    }   });
```

This is the cause:

The promise returned by price() call had resolves an undefined value (instead of rejecting with an error).  Your "await" wait for this undefined value and assigned it to "response" variable.

The price() when having problem have already handled the error and then print the details in the console:

```
Error: <html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>

    at IEXRequest.<anonymous> (/home/runner/ArtisticAridSite/node_modules/node-iex-cloud/lib/request.js:128:35)
    at step (/home/runner/ArtisticAridSite/node_modules/node-iex-cloud/lib/request.js:32:23)
    at Object.next (/home/runner/ArtisticAridSite/node_modules/node-iex-cloud/lib/request.js:13:53)
    at fulfilled (/home/runner/ArtisticAridSite/node_modules/node-iex-cloud/lib/request.js:4:58)
```

It wasn't really passing the error back in the chain to your code.

So on your question of "How can I catch the exception?".  Unfortunately you probably has no way to receive the exception details (unless you can control the error handling behaviour of iex).  You may consider to check whether the result is undefined and handle accordingly.

Comment: So are you saying that IEX is swallowing the error and not bubbling it up?

Comment: I think so. It also explains why the catch() after price() is never called. You may try to take away the await to check the promise returned by price(). And then do a typical then() catch() you will see the then() is called with a resolved result of value undefined.

Comment: I contacted the author of the library today and he advised there was a bug in the error handling after my bug report and has already corrected it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad to help. It’s in fact my first answer in stackoverflow. May you me the first one accepting my first answer :)

Comment: Typo: *may you be the first one accepting my first answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say for sure what's wrong without running the code, but there are several issues with the use of `async`, `await`, and promises in the code, and with creating [implicit globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). (Also various missing `;`.) If we sort those out, it may be that whatever error is occurring will stop being obscured. See `***` comments:

```
"use strict"; // *** This has to be at the very beginning of the compilation
              // unit, it can't be later in the code as it is in the question
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const { IEXCloudClient } = require("node-iex-cloud");
const { type } = require('tap');

const iex = new IEXCloudClient(fetch, {
  sandbox: true,
  publishable: "pk_2f78524e5........23c327e24b5",
  version: "stable"
});

async function getCurrentPriceOfBatchStocks(_stock) {

  // *** Declare `stocks_to_submit`
  const stocks_to_submit = _stock['stocks'];

  // *** Declare `response`
  const response = await iex.batchSymbols(stocks_to_submit).price();
  // *** Don't catch the error, let it propagate; the caller should
  // know whether the call succeeded or failed

  // *** Don't use `new Promise`, there's no purpose to it
  return response;
}

const batchStocksSchema = {
  querystring: {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
      stocks: {
        type: 'string'
      }
    },
    required: ['stocks']
  }
};

// *** This function never uses `await`, so don't make it `async`
module.exports = function (fastify, opts) {
  fastify.get('/batch_stock_prices/', {
    schema: batchStocksSchema
  }, function (request, reply) { // *** Typically old-style callback APIs don't do
                                 // anything with the promise an `async` function
                                 // returns, so don't pass `async` functions into them
    getCurrentPriceOfBatchStocks(request.query)
    .then(response => {
      // *** No `return` here, we aren't resolving the promise from `then` with the result
      // of `send`
      reply
        .code(200)
        .send(response);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
      // *** No `return` here, we aren't resolving the promise from `catch` with the
      // result of `send`
      reply
        .code(400)
        .send('Bad Request, exception: ' + e);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to refactor and add comments to this. I tried the code but it unfortunately still does not catch and pass back the error on response. The response is also a 200 when an exception occurs.

Comment: @IanSmith - If an error occurs anywhere within `getCurrentPriceOfBatchStocks`, the above definitely won't do a 200 response. Something *else* must be going on I'm afraid, outside the scope of this code.

Comment: I contacted the author of the library today and he advised there was a bug in the error handling after my bug report and has already corrected it. Thank you for your help!